# Split string into separate strings in PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

My script in powershell runs: *test.ps1 -dbo test1* => this works, it enters provided database

```sql
SELECT name FROM sys.databases
where name not in ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb', 'test1');
```

but if i want to enter multiple databases e.g *test.ps1 -dbo test1, test2, test3* => this is read as one string

```sql
SELECT name FROM sys.databases
where name not in ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb', 'test1, test2, test3');
```

How can I make in Powershell to split string into seperate, like that:

```sql
SELECT name FROM sys.databases
where name not in ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb', 'test1', 'test2', 'test3');
```

code:

```bsh
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    [Alias("dbo")]
    [String[]]
    $databaseName
)

$dbquery = @"
        SELECT name FROM sys.databases
        where name not in ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb', '$databaseName');
"@
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "$databaseIP" -Database "master" -Username $databaseUser -Password $databasePass -Query $dbquery
```

I tried with *split* and *join* but it does not work as i expected

Comment: FYI, `dbo.sysdatabases` has been deprecated for years (maybe since SQL Server 2000, I honestly can't recall?). You should really be uses `sys.databases`

Comment: Thanks, for information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NOTE: Any time you are taking parameters and directly putting them into a SQL string, you can open yourself up to malicious coders and SQL injection issues.  It is recommended to sanitize your inputs (make sure the input is valid) before you use them in a SQL string.  [Exploits of a Mom](https://xkcd.com/327)

You are getting exactly what you're asking for by putting an array of strings into a string without pre-processing.  A simple way of doing this is to fill in the stuff between the array members first, so add the `', '` with a `-join` like this (Adding plural array name for an array as suggested by @CaiusJard):

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    [Alias("dbo")]
    [String[]]
    $databaseNames
)

$databaseNameString = $databaseNames -join "', '"
$dbquery = @"
        SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases
        where name not in ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb', '$databaseNameString');
"@
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "$databaseIP" -Database "master" -Username $databaseUser -Password $databasePass -Query $dbquery
```

I hope this helps you out.